# Issue Create with Grid Column in Bootstrap 3.2.0

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following layout on a page(with Bootstrap 3.2.0):

**Here, Dynamic generate Column & Content in Column.** but, Here, Create following issue for me.

[image]

How can i fix it?  Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Responsive column resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets)

Using a a block such as the following after a column with a different height might address your problem:

```
 <!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
```

This will space the columns correctly on resize and layout.

Or, as a different solution, separate out your columns by wrapping the desired columns with

```
<div class="row">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After the sixth column, close your `<div class="row">` and reopen a new one right after so each line is separated.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">5</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">7</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">8</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">9</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">10</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">11</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">12</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're generting columns you can use some counter and `i%7` to add `.clear-left` class:

```
.clear-left { clear: left; }
```

If it's static enclose each row:

```
<div class="row">
...
</div>
<div class="row">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out this is clearly a float / clear issue.

You could use the `nth-child` selector to do the clearing for you. http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/1

Something like this should do the trick:

```
.col-lg-2:nth-child(6n+1) {
   clear: both;
}
```

The advantage of this method is that you do not need to change your markup by adding extra wrapper `div`s or empty clearfix elements. And browsers support should be fine: http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Comment: nth child is not supported in IE8

Comment: well, even microsoft stopped supporting IE8, so shouldn't we?

Comment: I am in full agreement, but some companies (like mine) still support it due to large user base being on XP.

Comment: I feel for you! We only dropped IE8 a few weeks ago and we celebrated this great day with a big bottle of champagne... Let's hope all the banks and big companies stop supporting IE8 very soon, and you may join the IE8-free club!